# What's the difference between the repaint and SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI?

Tags: java, swing

I have three JPanel, fatherPanel, childPanel1, childrenPanel2.

When I click a button, I remove the current children panel from the father panel, and add another children in the father panel.

Everytime I should call revalidate() and repaint() to update the UI.

Then, I know the SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI() has the same effect.

I want to know are there any difference between the twos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing supports pluggable [Look-n-Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/)'s. When you change the L&F at runtime you need to inform all your components, about this change using the method `updateComponentTreeUI`. Because due to new L&F the component sizes can be changed, Swing must call revalidate to recalculate the layout. Here is the code of the method `updateComponentTreeUI`

```
/**
 * A simple minded look and feel change: ask each node in the tree
 * to <code>updateUI()</code> -- that is, to initialize its UI property
 * with the current look and feel.
 */
public static void updateComponentTreeUI(Component c) {
    updateComponentTreeUI0(c);
    c.invalidate();
    c.validate();
    c.repaint();
}
```

So yes, you can invoke `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI` to inform your GUI about layout change but it's huge overhead (and can theoretically have some side-effects). Combination of `revalidate` and `repaint` is better in your case.